# How do you upgrade the plugins on a Jenkins X install?

Tags: jenkins-x

We have installed Jenkins X on a Kubernetes cluster, but are uncertain about how one goes about upgrading the plugins. I see a jx command for upgrading the platform; are the plugins used for Jenkins X tied to the platform version? If that is the case, how does one add plugins other than the standard loadout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no way to persist plugins, installed by the user. You need to build your own custom Jenkins X Docker image with all need plugins baked within.
https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/1562